# Extra "count" queries

Tags: cakephp

I've noticed a lot of extra count queries in my logs in Cakephp. They seem really unnecessary and slowing things down. 
Does anybody know what they are for and/or how they can be removed?

> 

```
 [194] => Array
            (
                [query] => SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `gpx_points` AS `Point`   WHERE `Point`.`id` = 81857
                [affected] => 1
                [numRows] => 1
                [took] => 1
            )

        [195] => Array
            (
                [query] => SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `gpx_points` AS `Point`   WHERE `Point`.`id` = 81857
                [affected] => 1
                [numRows] => 1
                [took] => 1
            )

        [196] => Array
            (
                [query] => UPDATE `gpx_points` SET `id` = 81857, `file_id` = 6, `zoom13` = '1'  WHERE `gpx_points`.`id` = 81857
                [affected] => 1
                [numRows] => 1
                [took] => 1
            )

        [197] => Array
            (
                [query] => SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `gpx_points` AS `Point`   WHERE `Point`.`id` = 71020
                [affected] => 1
                [numRows] => 1
                [took] => 1
            )

        [198] => Array
            (
                [query] => SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `gpx_points` AS `Point`   WHERE `Point`.`id` = 71020
                [affected] => 1
                [numRows] => 1
                [took] => 0
            )

        [199] => Array
            (
                [query] => UPDATE `gpx_points` SET `id` = 71020, `file_id` = 5, `zoom13` = '1'  WHERE `gpx_points`.`id` = 71020
                [affected] => 1
                [numRows] => 1
                [took] => 1
            )
```

Comment: You are probably running a find('count') somewhere. It would help to see your GpxPoint model/controller code.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily put a debug hook into the Cake internals to see where the query is being called from.

1. Open file cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php
2. Find the logQuery() function
3. At the top add:

   ```
   if(strpos($sql,'count')){ pr( Debugger::trace() ); }
   ```